# How to zip all the files in a folder individually?

Tags: powershell

In powershell, how should I zip all the files in a folder individually ? For example, I have 10 files in a folder which means I want to have 10 zips.

Below is my code but it only zips one file.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
   Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir,
        $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

ZipFiles "zippath" "sourcepath"
```

Comment: do that in a loop?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev do you mind to show some sample code ? I am new to powershell

Comment: @johndoe Did my answer help? Do you need a better explanation of how I achieved the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. So we get a list of folders in a path (-Directory returns folders only)
2. Then for each folder in the folderlist we pass it to the ZipFiles function
3. Function call will look like: `ZipFiles "C:\Logs.zip" "C:\Logs"`

   ```
   $folderlist = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Directory
   Foreach ($Folder in $folderlist)
   {ZipFiles "$($Folder.Fullname).zip" "$($Folder.Fullname)"}
   ```

Comment: ZipFiles : The term 'ZipFiles' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:2
+ {ZipFiles "$($Folder.Fullname).zip" "$($Folder.Fullname)"}
+  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ZipFiles:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @Andrey Read the full question I am answering, where you will see the question asker defines the function. Please be sure to understand that answers in stack overflow are for a specific question someone has asked and not every possible use case someone might have.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner that I just used that zips all files in the current directory using the filename and appending .zip extension

```
 Get-ChildItem "." | ForEach-Object { Compress-Archive -path $_.Name -destinationPath "$($_.Name).zip"}
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution it worked for me .. can you please provide script to remove those which are zipped ?

Answer (score 2):

use PowerShell go the the path that you would like to compress, do:

```
$folderlist = Get-ChildItem "."
foreach ($File in $folderlist) { Compress-Archive -path $File.Name -destinationPath "$($File.Name).zip"}
```